# Change view layer's size and view's position

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, view, uiview

I am working with Apple's AVCam example and I am trying to modify the layout to work with the iPad.

I'm trying to get the status bar to be present throughout, however whenever I enable it, (what I believe to be the `videoPreviewView` and its `viewLayer`) are in the status bar's way. So I need to move this down by 20px to make room for the status bar but I'm not sure how.

```
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:[[self captureManager] session]];
    UIView *view = [self videoPreviewView];
    CALayer *viewLayer = [view layer];
    [viewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    CGRect bounds = [videoPreviewView bounds];
    [[self view] setBounds:bounds];
    newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.bounds = bounds;
    [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:bounds];
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this under `UIView *view = [self videoPreviewView];`

```
CGPoint viewCenter = view.center;
viewCenter = CGPointMake(viewCenter.x, viewCenter.y - 20)
view.center = viewCenter;
```

Comment: For some reason that seems to have pushed it up even further. So there is now a 20px gap between the bottom of the view and the toolbar at the very bottom. I tried changing it to +20 and it did move it down but it overlapped the toolbar that time.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to to AdamG's answer did the trick, don't know why or if it is a viable solution. Anyone care to chime in?

```
CGPoint viewCenter = view.center;
viewCenter = CGPointMake(viewCenter.x, viewCenter.y + 20);
view.center = viewCenter;
CGRect temp = view.frame;
temp.size.height += -20;
view.frame = temp;
```